# reading a process memory not working giving error Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, readprocessmemory

I am currently trying to get my readProcessMemory function to work and I keep getting an error "`Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt`." I have been trying to solve it but I just cant do it. I have read other forums and threads to solve the problem and nothing has worked. I have been trying to just read an integer variable in a test program to make sure it works but I originally tried it on notepad and assault cube but nothing has worked.

Here is my code:

```
        const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;

        #region imports
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess,
    Int64 lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, UInt64 dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, UInt32 dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        #endregion


        private static IntPtr processHandle;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(readInt(0x003CECC4));

            Console.Read();
        }


        static byte[] readMemory(int memoryAddress, int bytesToRead)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("test")[0];
            processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, process.Id);

            IntPtr bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
            ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, memoryAddress, buffer, (uint)buffer.Length, out bytesRead);
            return buffer;
        }

        static int  readInt(int memoryAddress)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(readMemory(memoryAddress, 4), 0);
        }    

    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you are attempting to read protected memory. I realise that sounds 'trite', but you cant just read the memory of another application - there are a host of protections to prevent exactly that.

Comment: i know some programs have protection however assault cube is game modders/hackers start on as its an easy place to start reading and writing memory. ive had it working before on this game however this time it just doesn't want to

Answer (score 0):

You must run your program as administrator, right click your project and select "add new item" and select manifest file.  Change asInvoker to requireAdministrator, recompile and execute and it will work.

Secondly, you're using a dynamic address, if you restart the game it will no longer work, you'll be trying to read un-initilized or just random memory.  you should use dynamic methods to resolve your pointer chain and get the base address of modules instead of hard coding dynamic addresses.